# giving error on getElementById

Tags: javascript

I have to perform a animation in which two images are switched. The image ID is `image_anim`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>My Chill</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/Start_Page_css.css"/>
            <script src="../Java_Script/button_click.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var boxOne = document.getElementsById("image_anim");
            setTimeout(function()
    {

        for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
        setTimeout(function()
                {

                    setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        boxOne.src="../Images/p1.png";
                    },250);
                    setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        boxOne.src="../Images/p2.png";
                    },250);     
                        },500);
    };
     }, 3000);</script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="table_set_up_conn">
                    <div class="set_up_conn">SETTING UP YOUR CONNECTION</div>
            </div>
             <div class="table_image_anim">
                    <img id="#image_anim" src="../Images/p1.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="grey_layout_anim">
                    <div class="bold_write"><br>Now let's connect to your Clipsal Hub</div>
                    <div class="norm_write">1. Go to the Wi-Fi settings on your phone<br><br>2. Connect to the Clipsal Hub network<br><br>3. Return to this app when you're done<br><br></div>
            </div>
            <div class="table_centre_image">
                    <img id="#centre_image" src="../Images/p2.png"/>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function .
Function is :getElementsById
```

Comment: getElementsById its getElementById

Comment: Simple there is no getElementsById method

Comment: @Pallavi I voted to close the question, since it is no further relevant to anyone after you fix your own code. How do you find these errors yourself? In your browser, open [the web console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers). Usually it will show you a detailed error (incl. line) where something went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it's `getElementById` with no `s`.

Second, your JS code needs to be right before your closing `</body>` tag as when it's running right now, the element won't exist yet.

Third, you have `id="#image_anim"` which is not a valid ID. You want `id="image_anim"`. The hash (#) is used in the CSS to access an ID, so it cannot be apart of the ID name.

Answer (score 2):

Its not `getElementsById` its `getElementById`, remove `s`

Answer (score 2):

Your code lack 3 things:

You need to wait for the DOM to be loaded before you can access your element (or put the JS after the elements you want to access):

```
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback);
```

It's `getElementById` not `getElementsById`:

```
document.getElementById('myId');
```

And when giving a html element an ID you dont use the hash symbol: (#):

```
<img id="image_anim" src="../Images/p1.png"/>
```

Wrap it all together:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var myImg = document.getElementById('image_anim');

    //.. other code here
});
</script>
<img id="image_anim" src="../Images/p1.png"/>
```

Comment: thanx but one prob now the code is running but still not switching 4 times between the two sources have given.Its just changing from p1 to p2(once).

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple mistake you have made, You wrote `getElementsById`, But you have to remove the `S` so the correct word is :  `getElementById`

Answer (score 1):

You have used `setTimeout` inside for loop which will never give you the expected result..use  `setInterval` instead:
Also there was syntax Error in `getElementsById`

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head >
        <title >My Chill</title >
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/Start_Page_css.css" />
        <script src="../Java_Script/button_click.js" ></script >
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                var boxOne = document.getElementById("image_anim");
                var img = 1;
                var maxLoop = 4;
                var loopCount = 0;
                var interval = setInterval(function () {
                    ++loopCount;
                    if (loopCount <= maxLoop) {
                        ++img;
                        img = img > 2 ? 1 : img;
                        boxOne.src = "../Images/p" + (img) + ".png";
                    } else {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }
                }, 3000);
            }, false);
        </script >
    </head >
    <body ng-app="app" >
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="table_set_up_conn" >
            <div class="set_up_conn" >SETTING UP YOUR CONNECTION</div >
        </div >
        <div class="table_image_anim" >
            <img id="image_anim" src="../Images/p1.png" />
        </div >
        <div class="grey_layout_anim" >
            <div class="bold_write" ><br >Now let's connect to your Clipsal Hub</div >
            <div class="norm_write" >1. Go to the Wi-Fi settings on your phone<br ><br >2. Connect to the Clipsal Hub network<br ><br >3. Return to this app when you're done<br ><br ></div >
        </div >
        <div class="table_centre_image" >
            <img id="centre_image" src="../Images/p2.png" />
        </div >
    </div >
    </body >
    </html >
```

Answer (score 0):

> getElementsById is nothing in javascript. its getElementById, please remove "s"

[for a refrence](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp)